# Como fixar a posição de um header independente do tamanho da tela?

Tags: css, react

Basicamente estou construindo um menu hambúrguer e o mesmo tem essa barra azul como mostrada na tela abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quanto mais eu aperto essa tela, menor fica o tamanho desta barra, o que acaba escondendo o botão:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apertando mais

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma maneira de fazer com que o CSS deste elemento não deixe ele fazer isso?

Tenho o componente `Menu.js

Este com:

```
const contentHeader = (
      <div id="headerBlock">
        {!this.state.docked && (
          <button
            variant="outline-primary"
            onClick={this.menuButtonClick}
            href="#"
            style={styles.contentHeaderMenuLink}
            className="buttonMenu"
          >
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    );

     return (
       <Sidebar {...sidebarProps}>
         <MaterialTitlePanel title={contentHeader}></MaterialTitlePanel>
       </Sidebar>
     );
```

E dentro do componente `MaterialTitlePanel` tenho estes `Styles`:

```
const styles = {
  /*Propriedades do Pai Header*/
  root: {
    fontFamily:
      '"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif',
    fontWeight: 300,
    marginTop: "5%"
  },
  /*Propriedades do Header*/
  header: {
    backgroundColor: "#03a9f4",
    color: "white",
    padding: "5px",
    fontSize: "1.5em"
  }
};
```

Na `view` que engloba a visualização desejada tenho estes elementos:

```
<div style={{position: "fixed",overflow: "hidden",top:0, width: "100%", zIndex:10}}>
    <header>
        <Topo loading={this.props.loadingCardsConsulta}/>
    </header>
</div>
<div>
    <Menu />
</div>
```

Já testei diversas soluções e nada adiantou.

Comment: Cara faz um teste, troca esse `marginTop: "5%"` por um valor em pixel, ou mesmo coloque 0 para ver o que acontece, é só um chute pra testar mesmo

Comment: Não compensa você usar uma lib como mui? 
Já vai ter esses componentes prontos como o https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#responsive-app-bar-with-drawer

Answer (score -1):

Precisa colocar no alto um bloco com posiçao "sticky" afim que ele fica no alto. Tipo assim:

```
 #sur_container_menu_top_bande
 {
     max-width: 1200px;
     padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;   
     position: sticky;
     top:0px;
     background:white;
  }
```

Se vc coloca position: fixed; o DIV da parte inferior vai, no incio, se posicionar atrás do bloco superior e as dimensões não são mais consideradas.
Depois vc deve colocar um outro bloc que vai apparecer nesta posiçao com um display:flex;

```
 #container_menu_top_bande
 {
     display: flex;
     x-justify-content: space-around;
     x-align-items: stretch;
     border:solid #777 2px;
     border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:6px;
     background:white;
    padding: 10px;
 }
```

Dentrao deste "container_menu_top_bande" vc coloca o hamburger. E depois vc coloca um outro div para os outros elementos, etc...

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que eu saiba tem como usar algo como

```
header: {
    position: fixed,
    backgroundColor: "#03a9f4",
    color: "white",
    padding: "5px",
    fontSize: "1.5em"
  }
};
```

Pra ficar mais fácil, você pode criar um arquivo .css e botar uma classe para o header e moldar ele dentro do arquivo css

Comment: vou testar para ver se faz alguma diferença.

edit: Então, usando o position fixed, ele ficou bem menor(o que não é um problema), porém ainda sim ele vai subindo e entrando no componente acima dele, mantendo o problema, vou tentar colocar position fixed no componente Menu todo e ver o que acontece.

Comment: Eu iria dizer isto, pra colocar no componente Menu, ou na propriedade que você diz que seria o Pai Header

Comment: infelizmente independente de onde eu coloque a propriedade position: "fixed", ainda continua com o problema principal, vou investigar mais o que pode ser.

Comment: Tenta algo com position e vai tenstando com static, relative, fixed, absolute e sticky. Vou deixar este link para você dar uma olhada: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp e também https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: ok, vou dar uma olhada, para ver se algo ai me ajuda